# redirecting stdout in shell script

Tags: linux, unix

Either it is late in the day for me or I am missing something naive here.

here is a contrived example

```
#!/bin/bash
command="ls -al > check.txt"
$command
```

When I run this script on a shell it gives me error I guess due to the ">" operator. Anyway I can redirect the output from inside a shell script. I thought this was very straight forward:

```
ls -la > temp.txt
ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access temp.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do it using `eval`,

```
#!/bin/bash
command="ls -al > check.txt"
eval $command
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
command="ls -al" 
$command > check.txt
```

`>` is a special character in Bash (and most shells). It does not belong to a command.